# When use useEffect, I get a warning when passing less than variable dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my React application I have a redux store that contains a status of popup with the following model:

```
stateFilter: {
    visible: false
  }
```

On my page, I get the status of popup in store:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ list }) => ({
  visible: list.stateFilter.visible
});
```

I want to querying a database to filter with state varibale.
And I just want the function in my action run when popup is close.
To do so I am taking advantage of the useEffect hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!visible) {
      search({
        start: min,
        end: max
      })
    }
  }, [visible])
```

My action in redux action named 'search'.
And 'min', 'max' is the state variable that is changed when manipulating the popup.

And when execute app I get a warning like this:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'max', 'min', and 'search'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'search' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback
```

If I pass all the dependencies, the warning is turned off, but I see my **function running continuously** when the min, max values change.

And I tried using useCallback like this:

```
  const filter = useCallback(() => {
    search({
      start: min,
      end: max
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!visible) {
      filter();
    }
  }, [visible, filter])
```

Then I got another warning like this:

```
React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?
```

When the warning occurs, it means something is not optimized, but I don't know what is the best way to handle this case.

So what is the correct way to implement useEffect in this scenario?

Comment: The continuously run probably means you have a logic bug where setting min or max or subsequent call to search ultimately leads to a change in min or max or another dependency which leads to triggering again. You need to find that cycle and break it. Id you post more on the version where you have infinite cycles maybe I can give more pointed advice

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add dependency array

```
const filter = useCallback(() => {
    search({
      start: min,
      end: max
    })
  }, [search, min, max])
```